# Kerberos authorization as different user

Tags: c, oracle, kerberos

In my programm programmed on c, i want to connect to Oracle using differen user names without using password. That's mean, that user already connected to desktop in Active Directory and already entered his password. I don't want to known his password, i just want to create Oracle session for this user on Apache server with his user name.
 As i suppose, Kerberos methods can help me, but i'm not sure. Could you tell me, how can i connect to Oracle with different user names without use passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does support Kerberos logins.  see  [Advanced Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asokerb.htm#g1012894) for the 11g documentation.  It's been a while since I've used Oracle, but that code has been there for a long time.  It's kind of fiddly to get working, but it is quite stable once it is working.
to get the credentials through Apache you'll need [mod-auth-kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) or [mod-spnego](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modgssapache/).
I'm sure that you'll have questions along the way, but those pointers should allow you to evaluate whether this is an appropriate approach for your product.

Comment: mod_auth-kerb is what i needed as i guess, but i'm not sure enough.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the approach I suggest will work.  It wouldn't surprise me if you'll end up asking separate questions that are more targeted as you follow that approach; some here, some on serverfault, depending on how developmenty they are.